# Focus-follows-mouse in wxPython?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm developing an application that contains a number of panes. See the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4d2KN.png):

[image: screenshot]

- The left *settings* pane is a `wx.ScrolledPanel` that contains a number of `wx.Panels`.
- The top *events* pane is a `wx.grid.Grid`.
- The bottom *data* pane is a `wx.Panel` that contains a `wx.grid.Grid`.
- The middle *plot* pane is a `wx.Panel` containing an [enthought chaco](http://code.enthought.com/chaco/) plot.
- The right *detector* pane is a `wx.Panel`.

I would like to implement *focus follows mouse* so that when I move my mouse over the plot I can immediately zoom in or out using my scroll wheel without first clicking on the plot to give it the focus.

Similarly when I move my mouse over the left *settings* , the top *events* or the bottom *data* panes I would like to be able to immediately scroll the window using the scroll wheel without first clicking on the window.

Currently I defined a function:

```
def focusFollowsMouse(window):
    window.Bind(wx.EVT_ENTER_WINDOW, lambda event: window.SetFocus())
```

I would like to apply this function only on the four top-level panes: *plot*, *settings*, *events* and *data*.

However I need to call this function for each sub-panel or control in each of the top-level panes to get this to work. For example I need to apply this function individually to the *Measurement Settings*, *Analysis Parameters*, *View Settings* etc. panels.

Most likely the `EVT_ENTER_WINDOW` event is not propagated to parent windows.

Is there a way to get this to work without applying `focusFollowsMouse` to each and every sub-panel or control?

Thanks

Comment: I like focus-follows-mouse for my windowing environment, but having it happen within an application using a traditional widget set seems unexpected and counter-intuitive.

Comment: I agree in general, however in this application a user often needs to switch between the settings panel and the plot. I find it slightly irritating to continuously click on the plot before being able to zoom.

Note however that I haven't done any usability test yet. So it can just be the case that I'm mistaken.

Comment: This is Windows' behaviour - it works as you expect under GTK. Personally, I'd leave your app as it is, for consistency with other Windows applications, and install WizMouse: http://antibody-software.com/web/software/software/wizmouse-makes-your-mouse-wheel-work-on-the-window-under-the-mouse/

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will definitely try out WizMouse.

Comment: @Steven, if you put your comment into an "answer", it can be upvoted and then this question can be removed from the "unanswered" page. Which it should be since it really has been answered.

Answer (score 2):

This is Windows' behaviour - it works as you expect under GTK. Personally, I'd leave your app as it is, for consistency with other Windows applications, and install [WizMouse](http://antibody-software.com/web/software/software/wizmouse-makes-your-mouse-wheel-work-on-the-window-under-the-mouse/)